# Как считать русские названия?

Tags: php

Добрый день. У меня скрипт не может с LDAP считать русские названия. как побороть проблему?

```
$ldaptree    = "OU=Отделы,OU=Office,DC=bam,DC=loc";
................
ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(cn=*)")
```

Comment: Видимо дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем строчку сразу после:

```
$ldaptree    = "OU=Отделы,OU=Office,DC=bam,DC=loc";
$ldaptree = mb_convert_encoding($ldaptree,"Windows-1251");
```